# Prove that if $G$ acts transitvely on $X, |X|$ divides $|G|$

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification, group-actions

I've been reading Keith Conrad's [notes](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/grouptheory/transitive.pdf) on transitive group actions. In them, he states the following theorems:

> **Theorem 3.2.** Let $G$ be a group acting transitively on $X.$ Then $|X|$ divides
> $|G|.$
>
> **Theorem 3.4.** Suppose $G$ acts on two finite sets $X$ and $Y$ and
> there is a function $f : X → Y$ that respects the $G$-actions: $f (gx) = gf (x)$ for all $g ∈ G$ and $x ∈ X.$ If the action is transitive on Y then $|Y | | |X|.$

After proving these statements, he then remarks:

> As an exercise, show Theorem 3.2 is a special case of Theorem 3.4.

I'd like some help cleaning up a proof:

**My attempt:**
If $G$ acts transitively on $X$, this is equivalent to the action of $G$ by multiplication on a coset space $G/H$, where $H=G_x$ is the stabilizer of some arbitrary element $x\in X.$ The map $f:G/H\to X, gH\mapsto gx$ is $G$-equivariant, and by Theorem 3.4 $|X|$ divides $|G/H|$ and therefore $|G|.$

Is this proof correct? How it be improved, if so? Are there alternative ways of deriving this implication?

Comment: Your proof is correct but I'd say it's essentially the same argument as the proof of 3.2. Your map $f$ is just the bijection from the proof of the orbit-stabiliser theorem, so $|X| = |G/H|$ and you don't really rely on 3.4, instead you mostly rely on Lagrange's theorem to see $|G/H|$ divides $|G|$.

Comment: You could also take $x \in X$ and consider the map $f \colon G \to X \colon g \mapsto gx$, and then apply 3.4 to that map. That's a more direct argument.

Comment: Works for me.  Or you could just let $G$ act on itself,  couldn't you?  That would be transitive.  Like @Sverre said.